# Combine Threading.Timer with new Thread()?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have a console application that runs at :00 of every hour. This console application copies files at :15 and :30 of the very same hour.

This was my initial code, where I use a `WHILE` loop to check the current minute. I would like to replace the `WHILE` loop with a `System.Threading.Timer`.

Using Threading.Timer and without using a loop, how can I launch Thread0 at 15 minutes after the start of the console app and Thread1 at 30 minutes? I do not want to use 3rd-party, open-source solutions.

```
CancellationTokenSource cts0 = new CancellationTokenSource();
CancellationTokenSource cts1 = new CancellationTokenSource();

Thread Thread0, Thread1;

DateTime TaskRunDateTime = DateTime.Now;
DateTime RightNow = DateTime.Now;

while (!thread0Running || !thread1Running)
{
    if (RightNow.Minute == 15)
    {
        thread0Running = true;
        Class myClass0 = new Class();
        Thread0 = new Thread(() => myClass0.CopyFiles(15, cts0.Token));
        Thread0.Start();
    }
    else if (RightNow.Minute == 30)
    {
        thread1Running = true;
        Class myClass1 = new Class();
        Thread1 = new Thread(() => myClass1.CopyFiles(30, cts1.Token));
        Thread1.Start();
    }
    RightNow = DateTime.Now;
}

for (; ; )
{
    fileCount = Directory.GetFiles(destPath, FileDate + "*.xml").Length;
    If (fileCount == 20)
    {  
        // All 20 files have been copied because the two threads have finished
        RunExternalReportGeneratorEXE();
        break;
    }
    else if (RightNow >= TaskRunDateTime.AddHours(2))
    {
        // Task took over 2 hours to complete. 
        // Cancel Thread0, Thread1 and run 3rd-party executable.
        cts0.Cancel();
        cts1.Cancel();
        RunExternalReportGeneratorEXE();
        break;
    }
```

Comment: You could calculate how long until those times occur, then schedule a timer to start after that interval.

Comment: On a side note, I would suggest using the `ThreadPool` to manage your asynchronous operations (i.e. `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`).  The pool will determine if a new thread is needed, or if it can recycle existing threads.  Threads are not trivial resources!

Comment: That said, `Timer` uses the pool internally to allocate resources.

Comment: Why are not just using scheduled tasks?  Let Windows handle the scheduling, then you just write the code to get the work done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two `ManualResetEvent` objects that you can wait on. Then create two timers:

```
ManualResetEvent Copy1Done = new ManualResetEvent(false);
ManualResetEvent Copy2Done = new ManualResetEvent(false);

Timer t1 = new Timer((s) =>
    {
        Class myClass0 = new Class();
        myClass0.CopyFiles(15, cts0.Token);
        Copy1Done.Set();
    }, null, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15), TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(-1));
Timer t1 = new Timer((s) =>
    {
        Class myClass1 = new Class();
        myClass0.CopyFiles(30, cts1.Token);
        Copy2Done.Set();
    }, null, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30), TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(-1));
```

Those are one-shot timers; they'll fire once, and then won't fire again.

Now, you want to wait up to two hours for the copies to complete. That's where the `ManualResetEvent` objects come in. Create an array of the events:

```
WaitHandle[] handles = new WaitHandle[] {Copy1Done, Copy2Done};

// wait for both events to be signaled, or for two hours
if (!WaitHandle.WaitAll(handles, TimeSpan.FromHours(2)))
{
    // took too long. Cancel the copies.
    cts0.Cancel();
    cts1.Cancel();
    // you might want to wait here for the threads to exit.
    // otherwise you might have a problem with a locked file.
}
// and run the program
RunExternalReportGeneratorEXE();
```

Comment: There are several errors: `s` does not exist in the current context, `Invalid initializer member declarator` when instanstiating the class, and several others.

Comment: @user3605366: I fixed the obvious error (replaced `->` with `=>`). The point of my post wasn't to give you 100% working code (which I couldn't test anyway because I don't have your full code), but rather to give you the basic idea of how to solve your problem. Is there something here that you don't understand?

Comment: I just don't use lambda expressions that often and I didn't catch it. Sorry about that.

Comment: Your suggestion works well; the only problem is that it never reaches `RunExternalReportGeneratorEXE()`, it just ends execution. All instances of CopyFiles() ran and completed, but it doesn't seem to go beyond `if (!WaitHandle.WaitAll(handles, TimeSpan.FromHours(2)))`. I'll add some logging to make sure that it's definitely not reaching that code.

Comment: @user3605366: There was a bug in my posted code. The second timer's Lambda was setting the `Copy1Done` event. It's supposed to set the `Copy2Done` event. I changed the code here.

Comment: That bug is not the issue; I had fixed the error before implementing it in the code.

Comment: @user3605366: Does the program "end execution" (i.e. crash), or does it hang at the `WaitAll` call? If you change the `TimeSpan.FromHours(2)` to `TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)`, does it get by there? Is there an exception being thrown somewhere? Have you single-stepped this in the debugger to see what's happening?

Answer (score 3):

At the point you application starts you can calculate how long until X:15 and X:30 will fall. You could then use the [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah1h85ch.aspx)'s constructor to schedule the start time of the timer callback and the frequency.

Comment: do you think you can add an example?

Comment: Which part are you unsure about?

Comment: Since CopyFiles has two parameters [`CopyFiles(Minute, CancellationTokenSource)`, what would the TimerCallback delegate look like? Also, Timer constructor has 4 parameters; assuming I will call the method only once in minute :15 and then call the same method once again (with other parameters) in minute : 30, how would the constructor look like?

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to write the whole code here for you but to give you an idea what you can do with thread timer:

```
void CreateTimer()
{
    // Create an event to signal the timeout count threshold in the 
    // timer callback.
    AutoResetEvent autoEvent     = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    // Create an inferred delegate that invokes methods for the timer.
    TimerCallback tcb = CheckStatus;
    // Create a timer that signals the delegate to invoke  
    // CheckStatus after 15 minutes. 
    // thereafter.
    Console.WriteLine("{0} Creating timer.\n", DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss.fff"));
    System.Threading.Timer Timer stateTimer = new Timer(tcb, autoEvent, 1000 * 60 *15, 0);
    //Wait for 15 minutes
    autoEvent.WaitOne(1000 * 60 *15, false);
    stateTimer  = new Timer(tcb, null, 1000 * 60 *30, 0);
}

// This method is called by the timer delegate. 
public void CheckStatus(Object stateInfo)
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(DoWork), stateInfo);
}

public void DoWork(Object stateInfo)
{
    AutoResetEvent autoEvent = (AutoResetEvent)stateInfo;
    autoEvent.Set();
    //Change your worktype here.
    CancellationTokenSource cts0 = new CancellationTokenSource();
    Class myClass1 = new Class();
    myClass1.CopyFiles(30, cts0.Token);

}
```

Comment: Thanks. How would I invoke that timer from Main()? Let's say I have to call it 3 times (at :15, :30, :45), how would I do so?

Comment: I know what a Timer can do; I looked at the same MSDN link you got this code from. I see DoWork() calls CopyFiles() for :30. Do I pass the minute as parameter? If so, then how do I add that parameter to the call in the Timer delegate CheckStatus()? Or do I create DoWork2()? What is statusChecker? In the MSDN example it's a class, but in your code it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @user3605366 I removed the statusChecker name to make it clear. In my code as you can see I am sending the autoEvent variable from the Timer itself. You can send parameters like that. Try sending a List<int>, it will get that value for you. In there I have sent autoEvent because I wanted to stop the main thread from executing the other codes.

Comment: I'm relatively new to Threading, that's why it's hard for me to understand. Can you post a short snippet of correct code?